# Spring Data Rest HATEOAS Links and HTML Select Drop Down

Tags: angularjs, spring-data-rest

This is my second question in a few days about working with spring data rest and HATEOAS links.

**tl;dr**

*How can  my application use the link for 'manyToOne' attribute to populate  the 'current value' for an html select drop down?*

"Spring data rest" generated links behave differently than with "old school ids".

**Context**

- Converting an app to spring JPA and spring data rest.
- Simple 'product/category' table structure per below
- I've added a projection name 'full' to 'join/get' descriptions

*Tables*

```
*Product*
---------
Product ID
Product Name
Category ID

*Category*
---------
Category ID
Category Name
```

**Spring Data Rest Domain Objects**

*Product*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Products
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5697367593400296932L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    public long id;

    public String product_name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false,cascade= CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private ProductCategory productCategory;

    public Products(){}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Products(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public ProductCategory getProductCategory()
    {
        return productCategory;
    }

    public void setProductCategory(ProductCategory pProductCategory)
    {
        productCategory = pProductCategory;
    }


  @Projection(name = "full", types = { Products.class })
    interface VirtualProjection
    {

        String getProductName() ;
        
        @Value("#{target.productCategory.category}")
        String getCategory();
        
    }

}
```

*Product Category*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="productcat")

public class ProductCategory implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 890485159724195243L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;
    public String category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    Set<Products> products;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Set<Products> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

}
```

**Problem: Impedance Mismatch between list of Categories, value in object**

When the angular client retrieves a product, the product 'category link' for the product category looks like this:

```
href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/products/8/productCategory"
```

When the client retrieves a list of 'product categories', the link for the  category looks like this:

```
href": "http://localhost:8080/api/rest/productcat/4"
```

Here's the "select" code. The UI will only show select if "product.productCategory" maches one of the value for 'options'.

```
<select ng-model="product.productCategory >
  <option value="http://localhost:8080/api/rest/productcat/1">Foo Product Type
  </option>
  <option value="http://localhost:8080/api/rest/productcat/2">Bar Product Type
  </option>
  <option value="http://localhost:8080/api/rest/productcat/3">Baz Product Type
  </option>
</select>
```

*Question*

- How do I code my server API to make "generated links" client
  friendly?  What's the Springiest approach?
- Should I change the API to receive, for update,  "values" rather than  "IDs/Links", i.e. the Category Name,rather than the ID? (i.e. and look up the category by name and update it on the server side)
- What javascript/angular tools and techniques do you recommend for working with links?

Answer (score 0):

I coded around the problem by 'de-referencing' the "productCategory" value via javascript, 
 - retrieving the URL in the "productCategory" attribute, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/rest/products/8/productCategory
```

- replacing the "productCategory" attribute/url with the values from the HATEOAS links.
          pItem[pPropName] = data._links.self.href;

This approach brings a lot of complexity for a simple drop down. It doesn't smell right.

**De-reference code**

```
function dereferenceProperty(pItem,pPropName )
{

    var myRef = pItem._links[pPropName];
    if (myRef &&  myRef.href)
    {
        var myUrl = myRef.href;
        $http.get(myUrl).success(function (data, status)
        {
            pItem[pPropName] = data._links.self.href;
        });
    }
}
```

Usage

```
dereferenceProperty(pProduct,"productCategory");
```

After this 'de-refrence':

- Angular/Browser populated the drop down correctly
- an HTTP PATCH update the API (and tables) correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what do you mean, but if you need to get `Product` list within `ProductCategory` or you need to get implicitly `ProductCategory` within `Product` you can use, for example, [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections):

```
@Projection(name = "withProducts", types = ProductCategory.class)
public interface WithProducts {

    String getName();
    Set<Product> getProducts();
}

@Projection(name = "withCategory", types = Product.class)
public interface WithCategory {

    String getName();
    BigDecimal getPrice();
    ProductCategory getCategory();
}
```

Then if you GET `http://localhost:8080/api/productCategories/1?projection=withProducts` you retrieve something like this:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "products": [
            {
                "name": "Product1",
                "category": {
                    "name": "Category1"
                },
                "price": 1,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1"
                    },
                    "product": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "category": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1/category"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Product2",
                "category": {
                    "name": "Category1"
                },
                "price": 2,
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products/2"
                    },
                    "product": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products/2{?projection}",
                        "templated": true
                    },
                    "category": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/products/2/category"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/productCategories/1/products?projection=withCategory"
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you GET `http://localhost:8080/api/products/1/category?projection=withProducts` you retrieve something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Category1",
    "products": [
        {
            "name": "Product1",
            "price": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Product2",
            "price": 2
        }
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/productCategories/1"
        },
        "productCategory": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/productCategories/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "products": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/productCategories/1/products"
        }
    }
}
```

Working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example2).